# Generic RGB Profile Color Picker Problem

Tags: macos, color

I am using the *Generic RGB* profile instead of the *Color LCD* profile (in **Display** → **Color Settings**). But when the generic profile is active, my color picker picks darker colours.

For example, if I repeatedly pick a color from the picker, it gets darker each time. So it doesn't pick the same color, it takes the color and gives me darker shade of this color. This problem only happens in the *Generic RGB* profile, not in the *Color LCD* profile.

I tried this on my MacBook Pro 2011 (it is also Mountain Lion) and the problem remains. Is this a problem unique to Mountain Lion, or something else?

Comment: Can someone try it please? All must to do is open Display → Color Settings and click to Generic RGB profile, then open a color picker and try picking the same color on the top of picker over and over. If color is darkening then there is problem. And you can go back to LCD profile, all is done.